# Global Variables : Stylus Vue Vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, stylus

I would like to create and use stylus variables globally in my Vue Vite project. How can I import stylus variables globally to use within the script section of my SFC?

Here's my Vite config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      styl: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/styles/styles.styl"`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In my `styles.styl` file I define a variable like:

```
contentSideMargin = 50px
```

In my SFC I try to use a style from `styles.styl` such as

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
#main-container
  padding: $contentSideMargin  /* have also tried `contentSideMargin` */
</style>
```

but it does not work.

—

EDIT: adding package.json. There are no visible errors, the variable is passed directly into the css rather than its value.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.0.17",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.37",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.58.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are u using TypeScript?

Comment: I have set up a project with Vue 3 + Vie + TS + Stylus and it works:  https://github.com/TOA-Anakin/Vite-Vue3-TS-template

Comment: Thanks @DVN-Anakin, I'm not using TypeScript. Why would typescript affect this, though? It seems it should work either way.

Comment: It would help if you if you can post some additional info - what errors are you getting, what is your `package.json` etc.

Comment: Try to add a ';' like this ```additionalData: `@import "@/styles/styles.styl;"` ```

Comment: Thanks @DVN-Anakin, I added the package.json above. There are no visible errors. Placing a semi-colon didn't work lestra but thank you for the suggestion. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

**METHOD A) - CONFIGURING VITE FOR STYLUS USING `additionalData` PROPERTY**

This is the solution You have been searching for

*vite.config.js:*

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      stylus: {
        additionalData: `@import "${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/global_variables.styl')}"`
      }
    }
  },
})
```

**METHOD B) - IMPORTING STYLUS VARIABLES IN CSS**

If you don't want to custom-configure how Vite should bundle your code, all your `<style lang="stylus" scoped>` must contain definitions of `stylus` variables that you are going to use in the component.

Either u can define the variables explicitly at the beginning of `<style lang="stylus" scoped>` or if you have variables definitions in a separate file, you can import that file:

*App.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <div id="my-div">THIS IS MY DIV</div>
</template>
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
@import "./assets/global.styl";

#my-div {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: $c-text;
  background-color: $c-bg;
}
</style>
```

*assets/global.styl:*

```scss
$c-bg = red
$c-text = yellow
```

**METHOD C) - CONFIGURING VITE WITH CUSTOM PLUGIN FOR STYLUS:**

If you prefer not to use `import` within your components' `<style>` tags, you can configure Vite to automatically inject stylus files into the CSS of your app by including a custom Vite plugin `vite-stylus-import-plugin.js`. An advantage of this method over **method A** is that you can extra-customize the transformation of your stylus files.

*vite-stylus-import-plugin.js:*

```js
import path from 'path'

export function importStylus() {
    return {
        name: 'vite-stylus-import-plugin',
        async transform(code, id) {
        if (/.stylus$/g.test(id)) {
            return {
            code: `
                @import "${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/global_variables.styl')}"

                ${code}
            `,
            map: null,
            }
        }
        return null
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can use that plugin in your Vite config file:

*vite.config.js:*

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { importStylus } from './vite-stylus-import-plugin.js'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), {
    ...importStylus(),
    enforce: 'pre',
  }]
})
```

**WORKING DEMOS**

I have a working demo for the last two methods [HERE](https://toa-anakin.github.io/vite-vue3-stylus-template/) - GitHub repo [HERE](https://github.com/TOA-Anakin/vite-vue3-stylus-template). In the demo, the big red `<div>` element was styled using the **method B**, the blue `<div>` was styled using the **method C**. The **method A** is not in my demo, but it works too

Comment: Thanks @DVN-Anakin, I am aware of using `@import` to import those variables into my Vue SFC. However, that's not my goal here. Instead, as stated in my question, I'm looking to "create and use stylus variables globally" by injecting them into the vue components. Injecting them via `additionalData` in the Vite config file seemed for others, but not me. Open to any ideas towards that end, thank you.

Comment: @Nick Look at the updated answer

Comment: Thanks @DVN-Anakin, Method A is what I'm looking for. However, using your code I am still unable to get it to work. See this stackblitz that illustrates the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-router-starter-bqzpey?file=src/App.vue

Answer (score -1):

I think that instead

```
contentSideMargin = 50px

...


<style lang="stylus" scoped>
#main-container
  padding: $contentSideMargin  /* have also tried `contentSideMargin` */
</style>
```

The code should be

```
$contentSideMargin = 50px

...


<style lang="stylus" scoped>
#main-container {
  padding: $contentSideMargin;
}
</style>
```

Thanks to @DVN-Anakin comment and the link provided in the comment ( github.com/TOA-Anakin/Vite-Vue3-TS-template) to a working boilerplate - it's easy to spot the differences

**In short:** dear stackoverflow users - please read the comments! Members here put their best effort to try to assist without making to much noise (hence comments). If you skip them or not reading them properly - you may loose some vital information that will help you to solve your problem (which is kinda of what we are doing here in the first place)

Comment: Thanks @ymz, however your answer is not valid stylus syntax. See more here: https://stylus-lang.com/